# Sphinx/DocUtils to create custom documentation

Tags: python-sphinx

I'm trying to use Sphinx to create some HTML divs for each of my methods.

The problem is, I'd like to completely customize the code Sphinx generates.

I believe doing this would require creating a custom directive and telling Sphinx how to parse it.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are are looking to customize the the HTML that is generated, try modifying the [HTML builder](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/sphinx/src/93b1a4e9b789/sphinx/builders/html.py). Make a copy of the existing HTML builder and customize it to your liking. The [builder documentation](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/builders/index.html) may also help.